# setnumberformat not working with a specific Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I'd like to have your opinion on this issue.

Whether I'm using this code:

```
sheet.getRange("A2").setValue(val).setNumberFormat("0 000");
```

Or this code within my main function:

```
sheet.getRange("A2").setValue(val);
sheet.getRange("A2").setNumberFormat("0 000");
```

`setNumberFormat` isn't working with some spreadsheets that were created 2 years ago. I don't understand why since it works perfectly with a freshly created spreadsheet.

Did any of you run into this issue before? Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: As mentioned in the answer below, this feature is only available in new version of spreadsheets,the one that has a green v at the bottom. (And that defaults to 1000 rows instead of 100 :-)

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is that these will be the [old version of sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3541068?hl=en). You can see from that page that the new version contains some new [number formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/56470) options.

I would recommend checking the version of sheets and seeing if moving to the [new version](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3544847?hl=en) resolves the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! 

In the meantime I have noticed that this issue also happens with newer spreadsheets, for example with one created 2 months ago =/

Comment: I've tested it and .setNumberFormat("0 000") works perfectly for me. In the affected sheets, are you able to set a custom number format manually? (https://support.google.com/docs/answer/56470?p=drive_custom_numbers&rd=1) it sounds like it's either a problem with the rest of your code, or with the sheets itself.

Comment: It works perfectly for me too with some spreadsheets but not with some others.
With the spreadsheets with which the setnumberformat doesn't work, I can set up manually the formatting without troubles.
In my opinion, there is a problem with the sheets themselves. I though it was maybe a common issue with a simple thing to do to get it back to work.
If there is not, it's no big deal, I'll have to make do. Thanks anyway for your replies!